# Is it possible to filter angular.js by containment in another array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filtering

So if I have an array:

```
$scope.letters = 
[{"id":"a"},
{"id":"b"},
{"id":"c"}];
```

And another array

```
$scope.filterBy = ["b","c","d"];
```

And I want to have some ng-repeat to filter $scope.letters by only items that appear in $filterBy.

I want to be able to do something to the effect of:

```
<span ng-repeat="{{letter in letters|filter: letter.id in filterBy }} > {{letter.id}} </span>
```

And have it print b,c

I know this is a really stupid example, but is there a way to filter an angular.js expression based on the contents of another array object?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should try something like that:

JS:

```
angular.module('Test', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.letters = [
    {id: 'a'},
    {id: 'b'},
    {id: 'c'}
  ];

  $scope.filterBy = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

  $scope.filteredLetters = function () {
    return $scope.letters.filter(function (letter) {
      return $scope.filterBy.indexOf(letter.id) !== -1;
    });
  };
}

Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='letter in filteredLetters(letters)'>{{letter.id}}</div>
```

You can try [live example](http://jsbin.com/uxihug/1/edit).

Comment: filteredLetters() will get called _every_ digest cycle. So if you have in input field using ng-model in your view, that means every keystroke.  It would be better to store the results of the filter on a new $scope property.  Use $watch()es to update the filter results if `letters` or `filterBy` change.

Comment: While it will work (provided your app is very simple) I wouldn't recommend using this approach - as @MarkRajcok mentions, it's called each digest cycle meaning performance is horrible and I was getting errors from angular similar to "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Comment: Really helped me.Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

**Update**

Here's an angular module (based on @InviS answer) to easily implement this filter inside your angular application:
[filters-inArrayFilter](http://cyberdelphos.github.io/angular-inarray-filter/)

---

Here's the angular filters approach based on @InviS answer:

The filter should be like this:

```
.filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

where ***list*** is the list you're filtering (this param is set by default by angular), ***arrayFilter*** is the array you're using as filter, and ***element*** is the name of the property to filter in your list.

To use this filter you use your ng-repeat as:

```
<div ng-repeat='letter in letters | inArray:filterBy:"id"'>{{letter.id}}</div>
```

where ***inArray*** is the filter, ***filterBy*** *(the first argument of this filter)* is your array to match against, and ***"id"*** *(second argument)* is the element of the list you want to match against the array.

You can try this [live example](http://jsbin.com/owIXEPE/2/edit) using the angular filters approach.

Comment: What if i have to filter multiple columns ? Would `chaining` do ?

Comment: @dreamer What do you mean by multiple columns?

Comment: @Cyberdelphos how would you filterby if object key was a number? use $index?

Comment: @alphapilgrim Don't get your question, you mean filter an array of arrays?

Comment: @Cyberdelphos presumably this could also be done with 2 objects, filter one with by the other? Looking for the modification.

Comment: @Cyberdelphos, the link to angular-inarray-filter is 404-ing.

Comment: @A.Murray Solved it! Thanks!

Comment: This is working perfect for me. How could i return everything when the array is empty?

Comment: @data2info If you mean if "filterBy" is empty, you could add an `else` for the `if` statement and put a `return true` so all of the elements pass the filter, can't test it right now but it would be something like it.

Answer (score 6):

Quite old but I needed it and I had to change it a bit.
Here's my filter "notInArray"

```
app.filter('notInArray', function($filter){
return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
    if(arrayFilter){
        return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayFilter.length; i++) {
              if (arrayFilter[i][element] == listItem[element])
                  return false;
          }
          return true;
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
<md-chips ng-model="filter.SelectedValues" md-autocomplete-snap
          md-require-match="true">
      <md-autocomplete
          md-search-text="searchFilterChip"
          md-items="val in filter.Values | notInArray:filter.SelectedValues:'Id'"
          md-item-text="val.Name"
          md-no-cache="true"
          md-min-length="0">
        <span md-highlight-text="searchFilterChip">{{val.Name}}</span>
      </md-autocomplete>
      <md-chip-template>
        {{$chip.Name}}
      </md-chip-template>
  </md-chips>
```

I supposed this can be improved but not needed in my case.

Hope that helps someone !