# Is it possible display number of objects in one array and not in another array using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 2 arrays. one is **someMedia[]** and other one is **otherMedia[]**. i have certain objects in both array. If i want to diplay the items which is in **someMedia[]** and not in **otherMedia**, is it possible display using ng-repeat of angularjs.

```
Like
<div  ng-repeat="media in someMedia && !otherMedia"> </div>
```

Comment: just make the different array which contains the data from **someMedia[]** and not from **otherMedia[]** like **someWithoutOtherMedia[]**

Comment: I know that, but  i am asking, is it possible to display directly using ng-repeat

Comment: you can create a filter in which you can filter your array and return the different array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to filter angular.js by containment in another array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454900/is-it-possible-to-filter-angular-js-by-containment-in-another-array)