# AngularJS repeat filter by array

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to filter my `ng-repeat` via an array or object? i currently populate via http request like this :

```
  <div class="ibox" ng-repeat="data in appraisals track by $index">
```

But, Is there a way to make this filter by array so that I can have a check list which will filter by my `{{data.username}}`?

**Edit:**

here is the controller code :

```
 var urlgetappraisals = './dbscripts/getAppraisals.php'

                    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlgetappraisals}).success(function(data) {

                       $scope.appraisals = data;
                       $scope.nme = [];
                       $scope.nme.push("testname");
                       $scope.nme.push("testname2");

                    }).error(function(data){

                    });
```

so in my html :

I want appraisals to be filtered by any of the array objects (so in this case testname and testname2

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454900/is-it-possible-to-filter-angular-js-by-containment-in-another-array/21171880#21171880

Comment: Where do you put .filters? ive tried in app.js, in the controller and in services all throw error

Answer (score 1):

```
<input ng-model="username" type="text"/>    
<div class="ibox" ng-repeat="data in appraisals | filter:username track by $index">
```

Comment: i want the filter to be an array

Comment: Give your data list test and result data you want.