# Angular ng-options with conditional on value in simple array of strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, conditional-statements

I have two array shaped like this:

```
$scope.values_array = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'];
$scope.skip_array = ['string2', 'string3'];
```

and I try to use ng-options like this:

```
<select ng-options="value as value for value in values_array && skip_array.indexOf(value) === -1"></select>
```

This doesn't produce an error but nothing shows up in the dropdown anymore. Without the "&& skip_array.indexOf(value)" it shows all the options in values_array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="value as value for value in values_array | filter:skipValues"></select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.skipValues = function(value, index, array) {
    return $scope.skip_array.indexOf(value) === -1;
};
$scope.values_array = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'];
$scope.skip_array = ['string2', 'string3'];
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2211/)

**UDPATE:**

If you want to pass an extra parameter to the filter function

html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="value as value for value in values_array | filter:skipValues(1)"></select>
```

controller:

```
$scope.skipValues = function(anInt) {
    return function(value, index, array) {
        return $scope.skip_array.indexOf(value) === -1 && anInt > 0;
    }
};
$scope.values_array = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'];
$scope.skip_array = ['string2', 'string3'];
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2212/)

Comment: If I would want to add an extra parameter, in my case I want it to be able to skip it based on a passed int, how can I add this parameter to the function? (calling the function with 1 parameter and adding it to the function doesn't work)

Comment: @schuimer I have updated my post with a solution for your question.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)? Like

```
    <select ng-options="value as value for value in (values_array | yourFilter)"></select>
```

`yourFilter` might be something in the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21171880/2419919):

```
.filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element){
        if(arrayFilter){
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
            }); 
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `function` that will return the filtered values. You may also use a separate `filter` but a `function` should be much easier in this case

```
 <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" ng-model="mySelectmodel" ng-options="value as value for value in filteredValues(values_array)">

$scope.filteredValues = function () {
    return $scope.values_array.filter(function (val) {
        return $scope.skip_array.indexOf(val) === -1;
        });
    };
```

Here is the full working example

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/LkLask7y/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

> Html

```
<select ng-modal="yourmodalname" ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in arraylistofvalue | filter : selectedvalues"></select
```

> angular controller

```
 $scope.selectedvalues = function(value , index , array ){
     if (value.id == 1){
            return $scope.arraylistofvalue.indexOf(value);
         }

      }
```

> array list

```
$scope.arraylistofvalue = [{id : 1 ,name : 'value1'}{id : 2 ,name : 'value2'}]
```