# AngularJs ng-options repeat into repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in data.items">
     <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
     <td>
         <div>
             {{ data.items[$index].selectedBusinessType.id }}
             {{ data.items[$index].businessTypes[$index].id }}
             <select ng-options="businessType.name for businessType 
                     in item.businessTypes track by businessType.id"
                     data-ng-model="item.businessTypes.id == item.selectedBusinessType.id">
             </select>
         </div>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

In div models result is ok, but dropdown still didn't work

**DropDown without value screen**

[image]

**Scope data from back**

[image]

Can i get some solution what i doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to store in the `ng-model` of `select`? `data-ng-model="item.businessTypes.id == item.selectedBusinessType.id"` is an expression which will be `true/false`

Comment: Could you provide some snippet of your problem here or on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) for example?

Comment: I will try get value from businessTypes List, where businessTypes.id equal value from selectedBusinessType.id. Like: If businessType.id == 1, return first element on dropdown list, etc

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/JbjAvC8QYz9LPTnRCQhD

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need filter. Try something like:   (plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DiInzWMC2k8WZzuH)

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="$scope.data.items[0].selectedBusinessType.id" ng-options="businessType.name for businessType in item.businessTypes | filter:doFilter(item.selectedBusinessType)">
            </select>
```

And in controller:

```
  $scope.doFilter  = function(id) {
    console.log("selectedId:" + Object.values(id))
    return function(value, index, array) {
      console.log(value.id)
      if(value.id == Object.values(id))
        return true;
    }
  };
```

Relate to the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635805/4952634

Answer (score 0):

On angularJs version 1.5 work option like this:
[Plunk - Use angularJs 1.5x](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Ac7CjXs9U0UxKu4LPnp?p=preview)

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.items[$index].selectedBusinessType.id" 
          ng-disabled="item.CanChangeBusinessType" 
          ng-change="changeBusinessType(item, selectedBusinessType.id)">
          <option ng-repeat="businessType in item.businessTypes" ng-value="businessType.id">
            {{businessType.id}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

But this don't work on version 1.4+.
[Plunk - Use angularJs 1.4x](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Ac7CjXs9U0UxKu4LPnp?p=preview)

```
   <div>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.items[$index].selectedBusinessType.id" 
        ng-disabled="item.CanChangeBusinessType" 
        ng-change="changeBusinessType(item, selectedBusinessType.id)">
          <option ng-repeat="businessType in item.businessTypes" ng-value="businessType.id">
            {{businessType.id}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Second worked option - use ng-option:
[Ng-Option using](https://plnkr.co/edit/rUU7X43kSgLk9fFZT0RQ?p=preview)

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.selectedBusinessType" 
        ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in data.businessTypes"
        ng-disabled="item.CanChangeBusinessType" 
        ng-change="changeBusinessType(item, item.selectedBusinessType, '{{item.selectedBusinessType}}')">
        <option value="">-- Не указан --</option>
      </select>
```