# dynamic checkbox filtering in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi i"m new to angularjs  wanted to filter as like this format

i have three json values 1.phone manufacture name and 2.phone ram and 3. phone price

According to the manufacture the ram and price should be loaded and as per the price and ram and manufacture name the  product list should of filtered

i know basic filtering but can"t able to in three checkbox

[my demo plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/3GT33gHz5KK7PQVX6tym/)

Comment: Please include all relevant code and data samples in the question content. Questions should be self contained, we shouldn't have to go off site just to review your problem. Demos are great but should only be used to support what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: Also ...what is the question and specific problem you have?

Comment: Try with custom filter : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21171880/2419919

Comment: @priya are you allowed to change the json structure?

Comment: @aravind yes you can

Comment: @priya if you can elaborate it would be great to solve asap.!! let me know

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to create a filter on checkboxes in angular. What I would do is, for each foreign key of a product, link the ng-model of each checkbox to the key of an object. Then write a function that uses these object's to filter.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope , $http) {
      
    // mobile price details
    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/3el1e').then(function(res) {
        $scope.priceList = res.data;
           
    });
    
    // mobile ram details
    
    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qcj6').then(function(res) {
        $scope.ramList = res.data;
    });
    
    // mobile manufacture details
    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/52t8y').then(function(res) {
        $scope.manuNameList = res.data;
    });
    
    var allProductDetails = [];
    // product details
    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/42diq').then(function(res) {
        allProductDetails = res.data;
    });

    // set the filter selection objects on the scope
    // they will look like this: 
    // { name_1: false, name_2: false, name_3: false }
    $scope.selectionManuName = {}
    $scope.selectionRam = {}
    $scope.selectionPrice = {}
    
    $scope.filter = function() {
        var filteredProductDetails = allProductDetails
        filteredProductDetails = selectionFilter(filteredProductDetails, 'product_list_manufacture_name', $scope.selectionManuName)
        filteredProductDetails = selectionFilter(filteredProductDetails, 'product_list_ram', $scope.selectionRam)
        filteredProductDetails = selectionFilter(filteredProductDetails, 'product_list_price', $scope.selectionPrice)
        return filteredProductDetails
    }
    
    function selectionFilter(products, propName, selection) {
        var filteredProducts = []
        // prevent undefined errors
        if(products) {
            //loop through the product
            for(var i = 0; i < products.length; ++i) {
                var product = products[i];
                
                // an array of foreign keys, e.g. ram
                var productPropIdArray = product[propName]
                // check whether at least one of the values to filter on corresponds to one of the foreign keys
                // algorithm: 
                //  - start pretending no value is found
                //  - loop
                //  - if an id is selected and found in the product's foreign key array, 
                //      add it to the filteredProducts array and stop the loop
                var keep = false
                singleProductCheck:
                // loop through the values to filter on
                for (var selectionId in selection) {
                    // check whether the corresponding checkbox is selected
                    if (selection[selectionId]) {
                        
                        // loop through the array of foreign keys
                        for (var j = 0; j < productPropIdArray.length; ++j) {
                            productPropId = productPropIdArray[j]
                            
                            if(productPropId === selectionId) {
                                keep = true
                                break singleProductCheck;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if (keep) {
                    filteredProducts.push(product)
                }
            }
        }
        return filteredProducts
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.11"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


  ---------------------
  <div class="form-check" ng-repeat="set_manu_name in manuNameList">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" ng-model="selectionManuName[set_manu_name.id]"/>{{set_manu_name.mobile_manu_name}}
    </label>
  </div>
  ---------------------
  <div class="form-check" ng-repeat="set_ram in ramList">
    <label class="form-check-label">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" ng-model="selectionRam[set_ram.id]"/>{{set_ram.ram}}
    </label>
  </div>
  <br/>
    ---------------------
  <div class="form-check" ng-repeat="set_price in priceList">
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" ng-model="selectionPrice[set_price.id]" />{{set_price.mobile_price}}
    </label>
  </div>
  ---------------------
  <div ng-repeat="productDetails in filter()">
    <p>{{productDetails.product_list_name}}</p>
    <p>{{productDetails.product_list_price}}</p>
    <p>{{productDetails.product_list_ram}}</p>
    <p>{{productDetails.product_list_manufacture_name}}</p>
    /*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/
  </div>
  
     </body>

</html>
```